# How to call a php file to canvasjs

Tags: javascript, php

First time poster, and still relatively new to javascript... I am trying to figure out how to reflect information from a php file to a canvasjs file.

```
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        title:{
            text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"              
        },
        data: [              
        {
            type: 'line',
            dataPoints: [
                { label: "2014/1/2",  y: 60,  x: 2  },
            ]
        },              
        {
            type: 'line',
            dataPoints: [
                 { label: "2014/1/2",  y: 0,  x: 2  },
            ]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of the labels and datapoints etc, I want information from a php file (or how to do it to any type of file) to be collected then displayed into this canvasjs file.

Is there a way to do this?

Sorry if I'm not clear, I really appreciate any help I can get :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to make the file you pasted a PHP file, then use PHP in it:

```
<?php

$dataPoints = [ [ "label" => "2014/1/2",  y => 0,  x => 2 ] ];

?>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        title: {
            text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"              
        },
        data: [              
            {
                type: 'line',
                dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints) ?>
            },              
            {
                type: 'line',
                dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints) ?>
            }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Another way would be to create a PHP file that returns the data, and make an AJAX request:

**data.php**:

```
<?php

$dataPoints = [ [ "label" => "2014/1/2",  y => 0,  x => 2 ] ];

echo json_encode($dataPoints);
```

**ui.html**:

```
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onload = function () {
        var dataPoints = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            title: {
                text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"              
            },
            data: [              
                {
                    type: 'line',
                    dataPoints: dataPoints
                },              
                {
                    type: 'line',
                    dataPoints: dataPoints
                }
            ]
        });
        chart.render();
    };

    request.open('GET', 'data.php', true);
    request.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi rid, I tried the first solution you gave me and it works :) Awesome! Thanks heaps!!

But the second solution didn't seem to work... I did replace the top tags (body, html etc) and made sure the php file ended with ?> but no luck ><

Comment: can you please check my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401860/canvas-js-data-sampling-in-php) related to canvasjs?